# (Biological) Cell Surface

Tags: modeling

I would like to model a cell and I was really impressed by this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSSCj2yD70M

Needless to say that it is way to fast to follow it through, but does anybody know how to achieve the surface on the red blood cells seen in the first 30 seconds? I already experimented with noise and the displacement modifier, but it doesn't come close to the surface shown in the video. I looks like I am either creating a rocky planet, or a ball full of spikes.

What I did so far was modifying a UV Sphere with subdivision modifier set to view = 4 and render =3. I created a cloud texture with a size of 0.25 and used tohgether with the displacement modifier with strength =  0.2.

[image]

I can add more detail with the subdivision modifier, but it gets impractical at values above 4.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: This is fairly complex, not really on topic I don't think. Try using Fresnel, Displace textures, etc. I saw some Texture Paint, some baking, some custom texture editing, etc. Kinda complex process.

Comment: you have to post what your results and point out the problem you faced

Comment: My ultimate goal is not to create a red blood cell, what I want is a "normal" mammlian cell.

Comment: @blasthaus  see if this is what you want [blood cell](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/88030)

Comment: @Chebhou: Yes, this kind of rippled surface what I am looking for.

Comment: @zeffii: Well, I don't think I am lacking references, I lack experience with blender.

Comment: perhaps share a few references here and you might get more useful answers.